# how to show only child term on expose filter option based on parent term from url in drupal7 views?

Tags: 7, views

I have created views with expose filter in drupal7. In expose filter I need to show only child term.Parent value will be depend on url. This time all parent and child term are showing in expose filter .

Comment: Are you using taxonomy terms?

Comment: Yes.I am using taxonomy terms

Comment: You can use [Taxonomy display child term display](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display_child_terms) Module. But parent value not get from url. You can try.